# How to avoid getting duplicate responses from my telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

I wrote a simple telegram bot that after inputting a command it displays some stats. It works flawlessly except when it's being fed the same command more than once (different users using the command). Right now looks something like this:

```
me: /hello
bot: "hey"
me: /hello
user2: /hello
user3: /hello
bot: "hey"
bot: "hey"
bot: "hey"
```

The appropiate would be to just display one message if it's the same as the previous one.

```
me: /hello
bot: "hey"
me: /hello
user2: /hello
user3: /hello
bot: "hey"
```

I'm using node-telegram-bot-api with a polling approach (I'll move it later to use webhooks).

I'm only using the bot.onText/bot.sendMessage functions from the telegram api.

```
bot.onText(/^\/test$/, async function onTestText(msg) {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'hey', {parse_mode: 'Markdown'});
});
```

TLDR: if bot receives the same command more than once, it will reply with a message X amount of times. I need to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to implement a global lock inside your code, which will lock executing the code until. unlocking the code

```
let lock= false ;
bot.onText(/^\/test$/, async function onTestText(msg) {
 if(!lock){
  lock = true ; 
  await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'hey', {parse_mode: 'Markdown'});
  lock = false ;
 }
});
```